# How do to asynchronous I/O bound work correctly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to fully understand how to implement the async and await keywords in TAP. I came around this MSDN entry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

In this post you can read the following two statements:

> For I/O-bound code, you await an operation that returns a Task or Task inside of an async method.

> Here are two questions you should ask before you write any code:
>
> Will your code be "waiting" for something, such as data from a database?
>
> If your answer is "yes", then your work is I/O-bound.
>
> Will your code be performing an expensive computation?
>
> If you answered "yes", then your work is CPU-bound.

> If the work you have is I/O-bound, use async and await without Task.Run. You should not use the Task Parallel Library. The reason for this is outlined in Async in Depth.

The linked article is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth

But I don't get it, why I shouldn't use Task.Run for fetching data from a database.

I mean for the most methods I can simply use the Async counter part such as `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` or `ExecuteScalarAsync`

But how should I use a data adapter to fetch a DataTable. Consider the following method

```
public DataTable SelectData(string selectCommand)
{
    OpenConnection();
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Command.CommandText = selectCommand;

    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(data);
    }
    CloseConnection();
    return data;
}
```

I would suggest the following method to get my data async, but I don't know whether this is the right way according to the post on MSDN.

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectDataAsync(string selectCommand)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => SelectData(selectCommand));
}
```

Moreover, consider the following method:

```
public void Query(string sqlCommand)
{
    OpenConnection();
    Command.CommandText = sqlCommand;
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseConnection();
}
```

How would I write this method if I want to support both Async and synchronous? I mean I could write the same code twice but instead of calling the synchrounous method, I use the async one.

```
public async QueryAsync(string sqlCommand)
{
    OpenConnection();
    Command.CommandText = sqlCommand;
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    await Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    CloseConnection();
}
```

Again, the same scenario. I shouldn't use Task.Run for I/O-Bound work but I do not want to write almost the same code twice.

Could anyone clarify how to do this correctly?

Comment: _But I don't get it, why I should use Task.Run for fetching data from a database._ You should use ```await``` and ```async``` for interacting with a database, not ```Task.Run```, you probably got that wrong.

Comment: There is no way code in the caller can turn something that uses the non-async version of Query into your QueryAsync function. One option to reduce duplication of you need to would be to make QueryAsync the primary function, and the wrap it with Task.Result where you use Query.

Comment: @imsmn oh sorry, I put should there instead of shouldn't. I edited my main post.

Comment: "I would suggest the following method to get my data async" - this method will not really get your data "async". Your current thread is freed while waiting for result of `Task.Run`, but instead another thread pool thread (`Task.Run`) is blocked waiting for `SelectData` to complete, so in the end - nothing is achieved. If you want two versions - better leave only `Async` vesrion, because caller can wait for it's result synchronously where appropriate, however you cannot get async version from sync one (`Task.Run` doesn't do that as described).

Comment: Take a look at this: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) Short answer, no. Also this: [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Answer (score 4):

MySqlDataAdapter has a [FillAsync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter_FillAsync_10.htm) method. You could replace your code with :

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string selectCommand)
{
    using(var conn=new MySqlConnection(...))
    using( var cmd=new MySqlCommand(selectCommand,conn))
    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {

        DataTable data = new DataTable()
        await adapter.FillAsync(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

I removed the `OpenConnection()` and `CloseConnection()` methods because they *guarantee* connection leaks. Connections are meant to be short-lived and closed even if there's an exception. Creating them inside a `using` block the way all examples show guarantees they'll be closed and disposed even in cases where a `finally` wouldn't be called.

**Strongly-typed Results with Dapper**

Instead of using a weakly-type DataTable though, perhaps a better solution would be to use eg [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and return a strongly typed collection, eg :

```
public async Task<List<Customers>> SelectData(string selectCommand)
{
    using(var conn=new MySqlConnection(...))
    {
        var results=await conn.QueryAsync<Customers>(selectCommand);
        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```

Using Dapper makes it easy to use parameterized queries, by specifying parameters through anonymous types, eg :

```
var publishers = await connection.QueryAsync<Publisher>(
    "select * from Publishers where Name = @name", 
    new { Name = "O'Reilly" });
```

Try using that name with string concatenation ....

If you really want dynamic results, you can use `dynamic` instead of a specific type.

Comment: I don't worry about opening and closing the connections. This is manged by my class which helds the method. I should have made this clear in my post.

Comment: @MarvinKlein you should worry, because your code already leaks connections. There's a reason people *don't* use such methods and global connection/command objects. You can create a method that returns a new connection object, but a  `CloseConnection()` isn't needed when `Dispose()` already closes the connection

Comment: My class implements IDisposable and calls Command?.Dispose(); and                 Connection?.Dispose(); on destruction. Open and Close are working in the same way. if (Command?.Connection?.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
 Command?.Connection?.Open();
}

Comment: @MarvinKlein what does this offer except *widen* the scope of both the connection, command *and* the readers used by the data adapter? This isn't hiding complexity or encapsulating data access.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't get it, why I shouldn't use Task.Run for fetching data from a database.

Because that's simply shifting the problem rather than solving it; it will block a ThreadPool thread rather than the current thread whilst waiting for the I/O.

If your targeting a desktop app this might not be a major issue, but it would kill scalability in a web app.

> How would I write this method if I want to support both Async and synchronous?

Generally if you need to support both paradigms there will need to be some duplication, however, you can still reuse some of the common parts:

```
private void CreateCommand(string sqlCommand)
{
    OpenConnection();
    Command.CommandText = sqlCommand;
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
}

public void Query(string sqlCommand)
{
    CreateCommand(sqlCommand)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseConnection();
}

public async Task QueryAsync(string sqlCommand)
{
    CreateCommand(sqlCommand)
    await Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    CloseConnection();
}
```

> But how should I use a data adapter to fetch a DataTable.

Using the non-blocking [`FillAsync`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter_FillAsync.htm):

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string selectCommand)
{
    //...

    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command))
    {
        await adapter.FillAsync(data);
    }
    CloseConnection();
    return data;
}
```

Or you could use `ExecuteReaderAsync` in combination with `DataTable.Load`:

```
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string selectCommand)
{
    //...

    data.Load(await Command.ExecuteReaderAsync());
    
    CloseConnection();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Hi Johnathan, thanks for your reply. FillAsync isn't supported by every DataAdapter.It is for MysqlDataAdapter but not for FbDataAdapter to deal with Firebird databases. I just used MySqlDataApdater because it is more know by the majority of people. But I didn't know that MySql supports this method either. Do you know any other kind of solution if FillAsync is not available?

Comment: You could use `ExecuteReaderAsync` in combination with `DataTable.Load`.